# how to write a script to work whenever i clone a certain repository

Tags: shell

Is there a way to create a script shell to automate certain tasks whenever specific repositories are cloned? I am trying to create a script that can copy and create files in a repository whenever I git clone them.

Comment: Is the script supposed to run on your local or remote repository? And on what system is it running?

Comment: Hello the script should run on both local and remote repository. And by system do you mean oses?

Comment: Well, locally, you can just write a function or an alias for `git clone`. Remotely, the easiest way would be by using the hosting service, Most (like github or gitlab) offer some hooks. You can also use the post-checkout hook for git clone. See also: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout